# How to Configure Parameter Interceptors?

Tags: struts2

In my Struts2 applicaion

**I have a Jsp page with some feilds ,** like this

```
    <s:form action="customer.action" method="post" validate="false">
     <s:textfield name="cust.fname" key="fname" size="20" /> 
     <s:textfield name="cust.lname" key="lname" size="20" /> 
     <s:textfield name="cust.title" key="title" size="20" /> 
     <s:submit method="addCustomer" key="label.submit" align="center" />

  </s:form>
```

**I have created a Bean Class For that**

```
public class Customer {

private String fname;
private String lname;
private String title;
public String getFname() {
return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
this.fname = fname;
}

public String getLname() {
return lname;
}

public void setLname(String lname) {
this.lname = lname;
}

public String getAddress() {
return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
this.address = address;
}
}
```

**an Action Class**

```
public class CustomerAction extends ActionSupport {

private Customer cust;

public Customer getCust() {
return cust;
}

public void setCust(Customer cust) {
this.cust = cust;
}
public String addCustomer() {
return "success";
}

}
```

When i hit the submit button i m getting exception like this

```
com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor setParameters
SEVERE: ParametersInterceptor - [setParameters]: Unexpected Exception catched: Error setting expression 'cust.address' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@153113d'
SEVERE: ParametersInterceptor - [setParameters]: Unexpected Exception catched: Error setting expression 'cust.fname' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@18c8aea'
17 Jun, 2010 3:37:36 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor setParameters
SEVERE: ParametersInterceptor - [setParameters]: Unexpected Exception catched: Error setting expression 'cust.lname' with value '[Ljava.lang.String;@1f42731'
17 Jun, 2010 3:37:36 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor setParameters
WARNING: Caught an exception while evaluating expression 'cust.lname' against value stack
Caught an Ognl exception while getting property cust - Class: ognl.OgnlRuntime
File: OgnlRuntime.java
Method: getMethodValue
Line: 935 - ognl/OgnlRuntime.java:935:-1
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.CompoundRootAccessor.getProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:106)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:1643)
at ognl.ASTProperty.getValueBody(ASTProperty.java:92)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:170)
at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:210)
at ognl.ASTChain.getValueBody(ASTChain.java:109)
at ognl.SimpleNode.evaluateGetValueBody(SimpleNode.java:170)
at ognl.SimpleNode.getValue(SimpleNode.java:210)
at ognl.Ognl.getValue(Ognl.java:333)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlUtil.getValue(OgnlUtil.java:194)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlValueStack.findValue(OgnlValueStack.java:238)
at org.apache.struts2.components.Property.start(Property.java:136)
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doStartTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:54)
at org.apache.jsp.pages.SuccessCustomer_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fproperty_005f1(SuccessCustomer_jsp.java:139)
at org.apache.jsp.pages.SuccessCustomer_jsp._jspService(SuccessCustomer_jsp.java:72)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:377)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:313)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:260)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:436)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:374)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:302)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ServletDispatcherResult.doExecute(ServletDispatcherResult.java:139)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:178)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:343)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:213)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:150)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:48)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:86)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.intercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:161)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:105)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:207)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:74)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:127)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ProfilingActivationInterceptor.intercept(ProfilingActivationInterceptor.java:107)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:206)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:115)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:143)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.intercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:115)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:170)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:123)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:176)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.intercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:161)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:83)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:219)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation$2.doProfiling(DefaultActionInvocation.java:218)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.profiling.UtilTimerStack.profile(UtilTimerStack.java:455)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:216)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:50)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:507)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:852)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: ognl.OgnlException: cust [java.lang.NullPointerException]
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getMethodValue(OgnlRuntime.java:935)
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.getPossibleProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:53)
at ognl.ObjectPropertyAccessor.getProperty(ObjectPropertyAccessor.java:121)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlValueStack$ObjectAccessor.getProperty(OgnlValueStack.java:58)
at ognl.OgnlRuntime.getProperty(OgnlRuntime.java:1643)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.CompoundRootAccessor.getProperty(CompoundRootAccessor.java:101)
... 143 more
17 Jun, 2010 3:48:55 PM com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.OgnlValueStack logLookupFailure
WARNING: NOTE: Previous warning message was issued due to devMode set to true.
```

How do i resolve this ?

Thnks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem is just that your submit is not hitting the desired Action. The `action` attribute of the `form` tag should correspond to the action name as mapped in your `struts.xml` file. And, as states the [docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.8/docs/form.html), it should *not* include the `.action` (or whatever) suffix.